# How to enable Loop tiling in gcc?

Tags: optimization, gcc, loops, gcc4, tiling

How to compile a code using gcc, which performs loop tiling (Blocking) ? The -O3 optimization by default does not do loop tiling. I need to enable loop tiling in this flag and also, find out the tile factor. (E.g. cubic tiling or rectangular tiling) i.e. the internal tiling heuristics .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided the exact version of gcc, nor example code, nor result code, nor did you look hard enough at the internet, but possibly this already answers your question:

Strip mining is an optimization that has been introduced into gcc with the merge of the [graphite branch in version 4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html). See also [the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> -floop-strip-mine
>       Perform loop strip mining transformations on loops. Strip mining splits a loop into two nested loops. The outer loop has strides equal to the strip size and the inner loop has strides of the original loop within a strip. The strip length can be changed using the loop-block-tile-size parameter. For example, given a loop like:

```
          DO I = 1, N
            A(I) = A(I) + C
          ENDDO
```

> loop strip mining will transform the loop as if the user had written:

```
          DO II = 1, N, 51
            DO I = II, min (II + 50, N)
              A(I) = A(I) + C
            ENDDO
          ENDDO
```

> This optimization applies to all the languages supported by GCC and is not limited to Fortran. To use this code transformation, GCC has to be configured with --with-ppl and --with-cloog to enable the Graphite loop transformation infrastructure.

You may run `man gcc | grep '\-floop\-strip\-mine'` to check if that is a supported option. For the exact gcc version, type `gcc --version`.

Comment: My gcc version is 4.4.5. I read that the flag -floop-block performs blocking of code. My question is that, How will we know the blocking factor ? Is there any flag which can report at compile time about the blocking factor .. ?